# Image is undefined when binding a drag event after onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, coffeescript, hammer.js

When in coffeescript I try to bind the dragstart event on an image in an onload trigger I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ondragstart' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
image_url = "some.url"

@image = $ new Image()
@image[0].onload = () =>
    @image.on( 'dragstart', () -> false )

@image.attr 'src', image_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this:

```
@image[0].onload = () =>
  @image.on 'mousedown', (e) -> e.preventDefault();
```

Mouse down, in combination with prevent default..

In this example they do bind it like I do in the question though:
http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/slideshow/

Still wondering what I'm missing here..